# Post without form submit and GET

Tags: php, ajax

I was redirecting to new page start.php and passing variable in this way:

`window.location.href = 'start.php?&userid=`+ userid;`

Can I do it in this way:

```
$.post('start.php',{userid: userid});
window.location.href = 'start.php';
```

I dont want to use GET and Form submit.

Because on same page there are other processes which already post data to other page.

I tested above but on start.php it says var is not defined

**UPDATE**

start.php

```
<?php
    $user_id=$_GET['userid']; //When I use GET
?>

<?php
    $user_id=$_POST['userid']; //When I use POST
?>
```

login.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ThenWat</title>
        <link href="css/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/rateit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.rateit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
        <style>
            .header{
                background-color:#0B6121;
                border:2px solid #0B6121;
                padding:10px 40px;
                border-radius:5px;
            }

            .middle{
                background-color:Yellow;
            }

            .left{
                background-color:Green;
            }
            .url{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: block;
            }
            .url:hover {
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            }

            html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header" style="">
            <table style="">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src= "3.png" height="50" width="310"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                    
        </div>      
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <div class="middle">
                        <td style="width:40%">
                        <input type="button" id="loginButton" class="button" onclick="authUser();" value="Login | ThanWat" style="display:none; left:500px; position:relative"/> 
                            <lable id="lable1"  style="display:none;" ><i> Please wait .. </i> </lable>                     
                        <div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateit99" data-rateit-starwidth="32" data-rateit-starheight="32" style=" position:relative; top:-30px; display:none; left:300px" >
                            </div>
                        </td>               
                    </div>
                </tr>               
            </table>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var userid;
            FB.init({
            appId: '1412066',
            xfbml: true,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);
            function authUser() 
            {
                FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'email'});
            }
            function checkLoginStatus(response) 
            {               
                document.getElementById('lable1').style.display = 'block';
                if(response && response.status == 'connected') 
                {
                FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email,name', function(mydata)
                {                   
                    console.log(mydata.email);
                    console.log(mydata.id);
                    userid=mydata.id;
                    var name=mydata.name;
                    //alert(name);
                    var email=mydata.email;
                    var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
                    var a = JSON.parse(json);
                    var picture="https://graph.facebook.com/"+userid+"/picture?type=small";
                    // alert(picture);
                    $.post('user_record.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, userid:userid, picture:picture}, function(data)
                    {
                        window.location.href = 'start.php?userid='+userid;

                    });
                });

                console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('lable1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE2**

```
$.post('user_record.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, userid:userid, picture:picture}, function(data)
                    {                       
                        var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'></form>");
                        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+userid+'" />');
                        $('body').append($form);
                        window.form1.submit();
                    });
```

start.php

```
<?php
    $user_id=$_POST['userid'];
    echo $user_id;
?>
```

Comment: What is the code on your `start.php` page? Please add it to the question.

Comment: You could put a hidden form element (change it via JS if needed on the fly) and submit the form via post anyhow - then you can access it cleanly via the POST in the PHP.

Comment: when you will be doing window.location.href it definitely will not take the post variable to the next page. if you donot want even $.ajax then session is a solution.

Comment: Also, you can use `$user_id=$_REQUEST['userid'];` which will work for either GET or POST data - assuming they are set.

Comment: @MazIqbal: Thanks dude. But I need to user POST only. It's constraint for me

Comment: @Fluffeh: I appreciate your solution. But i could not figure it out. Can you please see login.php of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me. You need to add a new form using jquery after your first ajax response and then submit this form using javascript.

```
<script>

 $.post('user_record.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, userid:userid, picture:picture}, function(data){
   var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'></form>");
   $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+data+'" />');
   $('body').append($form);
   window.form1.submit();
 });

 </script>
```

Please modify it according to your requirement. Hope this helps

Comment: jazakallah, I used same snippets changing `data` to `userid` and `<?php
 $user_id=$_POST['userid'];
 echo $user_id;
?>` at start.php

Comment: But it says undefine index userid on start.php

Comment: i think forgot one thing. add method = 'post' in new form. I updated the answer. $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'></form>");

Comment: `$form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+data+'" />');` has syntax error. I  could not sort it but it's in placing value od `data`

Comment: can you post your code. how are you using it. as it working for me.

Comment: Can you please let me know are you able to get the value of userid here. alert of console.log. is userid value available? in this code snippet. i think it is not getting userid value.

Comment: No there exist value. I assigned manually `var userid="123";`

Comment: then what exactly the error you are getting as i tested it again it worked for me. if you hardcode value then still is it not working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40484/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-maz-iqbal)

Comment: your are missing $ with form variable. please add it and it should work